# Html tags not rendering inside tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using `.html()` to fetch content of a `span tag` and display it as tool-tip, But html tags inside span tag is directly displayed inside tool-tip without rendering.

```
<div>
<a href="#">Parent
<span>
<strong>It is a long established</strong> The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to usi<em>ng 'Content here, content here', m</em>aking it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages
</span>
</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(this).hover(function(){
        // Hover over code

        var title = $(this).find('span').html();

        if(title){
        $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
        .text(title)
        .appendTo('body')
        .fadeIn('slow');
    }
}, function() {
        // Hover out code

        $('.tooltip').remove();
}).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
        var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
        $('.tooltip')
        .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qA88d/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `text()`. Check the working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/qA88d/1/

Change:

```
.text(title)
```

to

```
.html(title)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use .html() instead of .text()

```
$(this).hover(function(){
    // Hover over code

    var title = $(this).find('span').html();

    if(title){
    $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
    .html(title)  // Change here
    .appendTo('body')
    .fadeIn('slow');
  }
  }, function() {
    // Hover out code

    $('.tooltip').remove();
  }).mousemove(function(e) {
    var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
    var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
    $('.tooltip')
        .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
   });
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qA88d/2/

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the html of the span, but then setting it to the tooltip as text. You need to set it as html as well:

```
var title = $(this).find('span').html();

if (title) {
    $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
        .html(title) // <--- right here
        .appendTo('body')
        .fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your JS from `.text()` to `.html()`.

**[View the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qA88d/4/)**

```
$(this).hover(function(){
        // Hover over code

        var title = $(this).find('span').html();

        if(title){
        $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
        // Change the line below!
        .text(title) // CHANGE THIS TO `.html(title)`
        // ^ Should be .html() [So it parses and renders the HTML]
        .appendTo('body')
        .fadeIn('slow');
    }
}, function() {
        // Hover out code

        $('.tooltip').remove();
}).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
        var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
        $('.tooltip')
        .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
$(this).hover(function(){
    // Hover over code

    var title = $(this).find('span').html();

    if(title){
    $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
    .html(title)
    .appendTo('body')
    .fadeIn('slow');
}}
```